# ubuntu 13.04, can't see source files of c++ project in QT creator

Tags: qt-creator

On ubuntu 12.10 I've been using Qt Creator for a while. After updating to ubuntu 13.04 I've encountered the problem, that I can no longer see my src-files in the project editor. I only see the .pro and .pri file.

I've checked that the build path is correct and re-installed QT 5. As well, I can compile and run the project as usual, but the src-files just won't appear in the editor. I used to run the project with QT4 (qmake-qt4 makefile.pro), might this interfere?

Comment: Do you have any disabled plugins in "Help"->"About plugins"?

Comment: @user2228947 No, I don't

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a workaround by adding the required source and header files manually via right-click on the project. But this is rather inconvenient as the source files are spread across several folders. I still couldn't figure out why QT creator does not add them automatically after I've upgraded to ubuntu 13.04 and QT 5 (downgrade to QT 2.7 was in vain, too).